# ever since upgrading to XCode 8, cannot use CGPointMake in debugger console

Tags: xcode, xcode8

Previously when debugging, I was able to do:

```
>expr mySprite.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
```

and see my sprite position update.

Ever since updating to XCode 8, when I do this I get:

```
error: call to 'CGPointMake' is ambiguous
candidate function
candidate function
```

Is there some XCode setting I need to turn on somewhere to enable being able to do this?

**UPDATE** I am using Objective-C

Comment: Debugging on every version of 8 I've tried up to 8.1 Beta 3 appears to be hopelessly broken. I can't print anything in the debugger.

Comment: It's really a shame Apple can't make sure their software works before forcing people to upgrade (when needing to build for the latest iOS).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 mySprite.position = CGPoint(x: 0,y :0)
```

and don't forget to import CoreGraphics

Answer (score 0):

It's really tedious, but you can do it via an intermediate variable as a workaround:

```
expr CGPoint $myPoint; $myPoint.x = 0; $myPoint.y = 0;
expr mySprite.position = $myPoint;
```

Unfortunately I have not yet been able to find a way to fix the `error: call to 'CGPointMake' is ambiguous`.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the annoying [CGPointFromString](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1624477-cgpointfromstring).